# Loop Doesn't Terminate in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function called "CurveInterpolateRecordset", which is as follows:

```
Function CurveInterpolateRecordset(rsCurve As Recordset, InterpDate As Date) As Double

    Dim I As Long

    Dim x1 As Date, x2 As Date, y1 As Double, y2 As Double, x As Date
    CurveInterpolateRecordset = Rnd()
    If rsCurve.RecordCount <> 0 Then

        I = 1
        rsCurve.MoveFirst

        x1 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
        y1 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))
        If InterpDate = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function
        'Do While Not rsCurve.EOF
        rsCurve.MoveNext
        Do While (CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) <= InterpDate)
            If rsCurve.EOF Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function

            If InterpDate = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate")): Exit Function

            If InterpDate > CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate")) Then

            x1 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
            y1 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))

            End If

            rsCurve.MoveNext
            If rsCurve.EOF Then CurveInterpolateRecordset = y1: Exit Function

        Loop

            x2 = CDate(rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate"))
            y2 = CDbl(rsCurve.Fields("ZeroRate"))

            CurveInterpolateRecordset = y1 + (y2 - y1) * CDate((InterpDate - x1) / (x2 - x1))
    End If


        Debug.Print I, InterpDate, x1, x2, y1, y2
End Function
```

This loop will interpolate a missing value for a specific date by interpolating using the values for the nearest dates.

I have a table of dates, some of which need interpolating, so I am using another function to iterate through the recordset and pass the function through each record's corresponding date in order to interpolate the value.

```
Sub SampleReadCurve()

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim iRow As Long, iField As Long
Dim strSQL As String
Dim CurveID As Long
Dim MarkRunID As Long
Dim ZeroCurveID As String

CurveID = 124
MarkRunID = 10167
ZeroCurveID = "'" & CurveID & "-" & MarkRunID & "'"
'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_VolatilityInput WHERE ZeroCurveID='124-10167'"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo_VolatilityInput WHERE ZeroCurveID=" & ZeroCurveID & " ORDER BY MaturityDate"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)



If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then

Do While Not rs.EOF

    rs.MoveFirst
    Debug.Print vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "First", rs!ZeroCurveID, rs!MaturityDate, rs!ZeroRate, rs!DiscountFactor
    rs.MoveLast
    Debug.Print "Last", rs!ZeroCurveID, rs!MaturityDate, rs!ZeroRate, rs!DiscountFactor
    Debug.Print "There are " & rs.RecordCount & " records and " _
                             & rs.Fields.Count & " fields."

    Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double
    MarkAsOfDate = rs!MarkAsOfDate
    BucketTermAmt = 3
    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, BucketTermAmt, MarkAsOfDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)
    Debug.Print BucketDate, InterpRate



   rs.MoveNext

Loop

   End If

End Sub
```

For one individual record and date, the first function works fine. However, when I execute the second function, the loop keeps repeating infinitely and the program crashes. I don't understand why this happens because there is clearly an end condition in the second loop. The recordset is only 76 records so not extremely large.

Comment: You should define your fields with the proper data type like Date. Then you can reduce to: `x1 = rsCurve.Fields("MaturityDate").Value`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the block that starts with `rs.MoveFirst` and ends with `rs.MoveLast` from inside your `while` loop. They should be inside the `if` but before the `while`.

Comment: for the first function or the second sub? I removed it from the second sub but I am still getting the same problem

Comment: the same error still occurs, do you think any other part of the code could be causing the issue?

Comment: I removed the block - it now prints "10/31/2015  6.844E-03" repeatedly before crashing, which is the BucketDate and InterpRate but only for that one specific date. I am not sure why it is calculating the InterpRate for that same date over and over again instead of iterating through the records